# Allocating a large amount of space for vector

Tags: c++, vector

I need to allocate a vector with `6227020800` elements. Its obviously too big for a regular call:

```
vector<int> largevector(6227020800)
```

I tried using new and its even too big for that:

```
vector<int> largevector= new vector<int>[6227020800]
```

Is there a way to allocate a vector that large?

Comment: Are you on a 64-bit machine with a 64-bit OS? Are you compiling for 64-bit? Do you have that much memory?

Comment: Well, then no can do. :( That code needs 24 GB of memory. 32-bit allows at most 2 - 4GB.

Comment: Q: I need to allocate a vector with 6++ billion elements.  Is there a way to allocate a vector that large?  A: not on a 32-bit CPU, there isn't ;)

Comment: Ok, then lets suppose i can find a machine thats 64 bits..how would i allocate it?

Comment: Then you need to: 1. Run a 64-bit OS. 2. Compile for 64-bit. 3. Make sure you have more than 24GB of memory in the machine. And it should work. Also, your second example doesn't do what you want it to do.

Comment: Ok thanks..The second one should be have a pointer on the left side.

Comment: The second one should be `std::vector<int> largevector(6227020800);` actually. You very much likely don't need `new`.

Comment: Maybe re-evaluating your solution for your problem could help. There are very few real-life problems where 24 GB of memory is needed **the same time**. What do you intend to accomplish? Maybe `vector` is not the right data structure for you, or maybe you could work on only smaller portions of your data at a time, without loading everything at once.

Comment: Using `new` isn't likely to help enough to notice. A `vector` object (itself) is quite small (a pointer, and a couple of size_t's). At least with the "stock" allocator, space for the data will be allocated from the free store even when the `vector` object itself is allocated automatically.

Comment: @Mysticial: Just remember that on a system that can address 24 Gb, there's at least a reasonable chance that `int` will be 8 bytes, so this may require ~48 Gb of storage.

Comment: Do you really need random-access of that whole bunch of data? If so, your code is okay in most 64bit applications, but will rely on the system's caching mechanism, which is not always quite reliable,  if you don't have enough physical memory. You may want implement your own cache for the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [stxxl](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/) library.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* need that much space, consider constructing a class which makes a file look like a random access iterator. To make it faster, let it contain a local buffer of 64M or so that acts like a cache.